# PHP on Ubuntu/Apache/MySQL server - no output in browser

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, php-7

I've just installed Apache, MySQL and PHP 7 on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I began by installing PHP 5.5, and then upgraded to PHP 7 - although admittedly I didn't test PHP 5.5 before upgrading. Probably should have done that.

I've created a test PHP script (info.php) to see if everything is working:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

The script executes and displays the phpinfo output as expected when I run it in the Terminal, but when I open it in a browser I get a blank screen. Have checked to make sure I have the right URL etc.

I also get a blank screen if I try the following:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

If I add HTML elements before the PHP code, these are displayed in the browser just fine.

I've turned display_errors to On in php.ini, and checked the Apache error log, which isn't showing anything strange. I can't find a PHP error log in the etc/php/7.0 folder or any of its subfolders.

I have noticed that in the etc/php5 folder I have three subfolders: apache2, cli and mods-available - but in the etc/php/7.0 folder I have no apache2 subfolder - in its place I have a subfolder named fpm.

This is suggesting to me that I simply don't have PHP7 set up as an Apache module, but maybe someone could confirm this for me? I'm not sure how to check this.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Thanks in advance,

Gareth

Comment: do you have run apache2 ? "service apache2 start" ? do you have some errors message ?

Comment: Did you restart your Apache after installing PHP?

Comment: check php log file  and server log file to more info

Comment: Thanks guys - yes, I restarted Apache after installing PHP, and just did it again just to be sure. Still no output. Where is the PHP log file located? I couldn't find it earlier...

Comment: View source on that white page.  Do you see your PHP code or just blank?  Is mod_php enabled or are you using fcgi?

Comment: OK, a little more info: I've edited php.ini and added the line "error_log = /var/log/php-scripts.log". Did this to all four instances of php.ini that I could find (php5/cli/php.ini; php5/apache2/php.ini; php/7.0/cli/php.ini; php/7.0/fpm/php.ini). Restarted Apache2, refreshed the browser, repeated both these steps, and PHP doesn't seem to be creating any log files...

Comment: Viewed the source and it's showing the test PHP code I created. How do I check if mod_php is enabled?

Comment: Problem solved! I hadn't installed libapache2-mod-php7.0 - installed that and all is working fine now. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here turned out to be that I simply hadn't installed mod_php as part of the PHP 7 installation process.

To rectify this I entered the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Everything appears to be working as expected now.